# Limit wp_query to post_status Publish after the_query has been set

Tags: wordpress

I have some code that displays a specific post type in a list. Some other file (not sure which one) is determining the WP_query `$the_query`. I want to modify this query to only show `post_status = publish`.

I have the following code prior to displaying the content:

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    ...
```

I want to filter `$the_query` to show only `post_status = publish`. I tried this (just prior to the if statement) without luck:

```
$the_query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );
```

Posts of type `sold` (a custom post type I added) still show up. How might I modify `the_query` to only show posts with the `post_status` set to publish after `the_query` has been created and set?

Another approach might be just to exclude all posts with the `post_status` set to `sold`.

EDIT:
I got my code working by reseting the_query all together (code below). I would still like to know if it is possible to modify the query after the fact. I tried `remove_query_arg( $key, $query )`, but that didn't work.

Resetting the_query (not the solution I was looking for):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: **From [WP Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#status-parameters)**: `post_status` (*string / array*) – use post status. Retrieves posts by post status. *Default value is `publish`*, but if the *user is logged in, `private`* is added. *Public custom post statuses are also included by default.* And if the query is run in an admin context (administration area or AJAX call), protected statuses are added too. By default protected statuses are ‘future‘, ‘draft‘ and ‘pending‘.

Comment: Thanks! Based on this knowledge, is is possible to then limit $the_query to post_status = publish only? That’s what I can’t figure out.